# Java Miglayout wrap JPanels

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I am trying to figure out why I can not wrap after adding a JPanel. My goal here is to have a class build my JPanels and then I will add it to the main screen with all JPanels stacked on one another. I can get this to work if I replace the JPanels with JLables. Here are my current results:

```
JPanel zPanel = new JPanel();
    for(int i = 0; i < zones.size(); i++ )
    {
        JLabel zLabel = new JLabel(zones.get(i));
        zPanel.add(zLabel);
        grid.add(zPanel,"wrap");
    }
```

[image: Failed Test]

And what I am trying to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < zones.size(); i++ )
    {
        JLabel zLabel = new JLabel(zones.get(i));
        grid.add(zLabel,"wrap");
    }
```

[image: Passed Test]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're adding `JLabel` into `JPanel`, then you need to make it wrap inside the `JPanel` itself. And, add the `zPanel` when all of the children is populated.

```
JPanel zPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 1");
for(int i = 0; i < zones.size(); i++ )
{
    JLabel zLabel = new JLabel(zones.get(i));
    zPanel.add(zLabel);
}
grid.add(zPanel,"wrap");
```

Comment: The problem is not the JLabels not wrapping. That is working correctly as seen in bottom picture. The problem is the JPanels are not wrapping as each JLabel has a separate JPanel.

Comment: on the top code, i see that only on zpanel declared, therefore, all JLabel has the same JPanel parent.

Comment: *Facepalm* that would be it. Mind editing your answer so i can mark that correct?

Comment: but if you declare new JPanel on the fly, eg, inside the `for` statement, you probably will lose reference to the panel.

Comment: Right but for the project I am working on I don't need to reference it again.